# hosting a webapp in azure VM with windows server

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, virtual-machines, azure

Problem: I have an azure webapp running and i would like to transfer it to an azure VM since the webapp needs to be integrated to payment platform which require testing of network connectivity between my app and payment platform server i.e bringing up the tunnel, and establishing a connection to payment platform servers [this can only be done if using a VM - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992929/configuring-multiple-ip-address-to-point-to-azure-webapp]

Therefore how would i also create a VM and host my web app (with a custom domain bought in azure) like the way azure offers it web app bundle and also configure SSL, have FTP access and other webapp feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install your web app as you would on any other local- or cloud-hosted server/vm. Since you're talking about Windows Server, that means maybe RDP'ing in and setting things up manually, pulling your app from source control, running various setup/install scripts/apps, etc.

The Azure-specific things will be around:

- Storage (e.g. attached disks)
- Networking (e.g. placing the VM in a vnet)
- Scaling (e.g. making sure, when going to a multi-VM setup, having them in an availability group for HA purposes) and load balancing
- Port-opening (e.g. allowing inbound content on port 80/443)
- IP restrictions (e.g. IP-filtering on inbound ports)
- Fixed IP address (useful if outbound services require whitelist)
- Automated installs (e.g. running a script when a new VM is started, to automate installs)

I'm sure there are other things, but bottom line is, you have to configure the VM. And the VHD is stored in persistent storage (blob storage), which survive reboots.